# typename to function name mapping at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, wrapper

Things I want to achieve is similar with that in this post: [Select function name based on template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813889/select-function-name-based-on-template-parameter)

In a c library, to handle different numeric types (float, double, complex -float, complex-double), there will be functions with different names.

when creating a wrapper of such a c library, I would like to figure out a way to achieve an effect of overloading and use same function name for all numeric types. Now I use template specialization：

```
#include <iostream>

float saxpy(float x) {
    return (1-x);
}

double daxpy(double x) {
    return (1+x);
}

template <typename T> 
T axpy(T x);

template<>
inline float axpy<float>(float x) {
    return saxpy(x);
}

template<>
inline double axpy<double>(double x) {
    return daxpy(x);
}


int main() {

    auto z0 = axpy(1.0f);
    auto z1 = axpy(1.0);

    std::cout << z0 << " " << z1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There's another way using type traits:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

float saxpy(float x) {
    return (1-x);
}

double daxpy(double x) {
    return (1+x);
}


struct saxpy_traits {
    static float feval(float x) { return saxpy(x); }
};

struct daxpy_traits {
    static double feval(double x) { return daxpy(x); }
};


template <typename T>
struct axpy_traits {
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, float>::value, saxpy_traits, daxpy_traits>::type Func;
    inline static T feval(T x) { 
        return Func::feval(x); 
    }
};

template<typename T>
inline T axpy(T x) {
    return axpy_traits<T>::feval(x);
}


int main() {

    auto z0 = axpy(1.0f);
    auto z1 = axpy(1.0);

    std::cout << z0 << " " << z1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there more elegant ways? Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid, "Is there more elegant ways?" is way to broad. What is it that you do not like about your approach?

Comment: What about two simple overloaded functions `float axpy(float);` and `double axpy(double);`?

Comment: @tobi303 yes "elegant" is ambiguous. what I expect, is mostly shorter code.  code like this would be ideal, I know it's impossible now.
template<typename T>
inline T axpy(T x) {
 return (T==float)? saxpy(x) : daxpy(x);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know what exactly qualifies as "elegant", I propose two alternative approaches:

```
float saxpy(float x)
{
  return 1.0f - x;
}



double daxpy(double x)
{
  return 1.0 + x;
}



namespace v1 {

float axpy(float x) { return saxpy(x); }

double axpy(double x) { return daxpy(x); }

} // namespace v1



namespace v2 {

struct Axpy
{
  float operator()(float x) const { return saxpy(x); }

  double operator()(double x) const { return daxpy(x); }
};

static constexpr Axpy axpy;

} // namespace v2
```

The first version simply defines two overloaded functions. This is similar to the approach taken by the standard library, e.g. `std::sqrt`.

The second version defines a function object that has an overloaded `operator()`. This version allows code auch as

```
  std::vector<float> fs { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f };
  std::vector<float> rs(fs.size());
  std::transform(fs.begin(), fs.end(), rs.begin(), v2::axpy);
```

which does not compile with the first version.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Both versions is better than my solution, I think.  In fact I am using BLAS/LAPACK . Here is its header file: https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/develop/common_lapack.h